# Square matrices A and B commute if and only if they share the same generalized eigenspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I found a couple of proofs for this theorem but only for the case when A and B are diagonalizable, thus the eigenspace that they share is not the generalized one.

Im looking for the proof (or literature that points to the proof) when A and B are non-diagonalizable matrices.

Thanks

Joao

Comment: Did you mean that "matrices commute if all their eigenspaces are common"? And, respectively, "all generalised eigenspaces"

Comment: Your proposition, a little more carefully stated, seems reasonable, though I haven't seen it.  If you want a theorem about arbitrary commuting matrices, you may note that any family of commuting matrices can be unitarily simultaneously upper-triangularized.

Comment: Never mind, your statement is false!

Answer (score 1):

The statement, as written (and as I could potentially imagine it being rewritten) is false.

For example, the matrices
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}, \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}
$$
both have the generalized eigenspace $\Bbb R^2$ associated with $\lambda = 0$.  However, they do not commute.

Comment: See the result I mentioned [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneously_triangularizable#Simultaneous_triangularisability).  This applies to any pair of commuting matrices.

Comment: Ok, but do these results on triangularisability mean that, if 2 matrices commute then they share the same generalized eigenspace?

Comment: I don't think that there's a connection between one and the other.  However, I think that this direction of the implication is true.

Comment: Ye, thats why Im looking for a proof on that direction of the implication, still thankz for the help

Comment: Well, that wasn't what you originally said you were looking for (see your title).  I might update this answer if I think of something.  In the mean time, you might want to post a new question, making it clear exactly what you're looking for now.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Would it still be false if we restrict to the cases where the eigenvalues are non-zero?

Comment: @mathnoob123 Yes. For example, just add the identity matrix to each of the matrices in my answer